# Where to get historical weather forecast?

Tags: weather

With weather being quite often an important external data. I'm trying to find where could I get **historical weather forecast**.

(I am **not** interested in where to get **past weather**)

Comment: What is it that you want exactly?

Comment: Ok I see it can be completely misunderstood so to clarify : I want to find a service where I can, for example, ask today (2015/06/19) what was the weather forecast last year (2014/06/19). And the answer would be : Last year (2014/06/19) we forecasted that tomorrow (2014/06/20) would be a nice day with High 20°C and Low 12°C and blablabla (as much metrics as possible) and the day after tomorrow (2014/06/21) would be blabla  same as before) and this for as much day as possible (maximum 14).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Forecast.io](http://forecast.io/) has an API that delivers historical forecasts. You can call a past date and time get the daily, hourly, and minute forecasts (in addition to actual forecasts). That is, ask for the weather on April 16th and will include forecasts for April 20th in the daily summaries.

It's free for under 1,000 calls per day, and then $1 for 10,000 calls--a pretty reasonable price.

Comment: Sure. I hope this suffices your requirements.

Comment: forecast.io is now being forwarded to darksky.net and they state in their FAQ that they do NOT provide historical forecasts.